# whats the difference between listing views in the app.js rather than a controller in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

What is the difference between list views within the view object of application set-up:

```
  Ext.application({
    models: [
...        
    ],
    views: [
        'Login',
        'Home       
    ],
```

and listing them in the config object of a controller in sencha touch?

```
   config: {
        views: [
            'Login',
            'View'      
        ],
```

Comment: The API Doc doesn't mention any difference between the two. In my app I load views in the profile and not in controller or app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Dependencies and MVC](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/mvc_dependencies-section-5) :

> The general rule when deciding where to declare each dependency is to
>   keep your classes completely self-contained. For example, if you have
>   a view that contains several other views, you should declare those
>   dependencies inside the view class, not the application

Hope this helps